# When placing a subclassed PFLogInViewController object in a UIView, why does it appear outside the frame?

Tags: ios

For a project I’m working on, I need to heavily customise the Parse.com login screen.

I realise that I need to subclass the `PFLogInViewController`, as well as do most of the modifications within the `viewDidLayoutSubviews` method. Also, I know I will eventually need to place elements of the `PFLogInViewController` into a `UIView` (which I’ll then place in a `UITableViewCell`), however I’m running into a strange problem.

When I try to add the `self.loginview.dismissButton` as a subview of a UIView I’ve called testView, the dismissButton does not appear within testView’s frame, it appears well outside of it (I set the x and y values of the dismissButton both to 0). However when I set `testView.hidden` to YES both objects are hidden.

Does anyone have any idea what I am doing wrong? Or perhaps any suggestion to work around this? I’ve listed the relevant code below

Thanks in advance.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
[super viewDidLoad];

[self.logInView.dismissButton removeFromSuperview];
UIView *testView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(50, 50, 50, 50)];
[testView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor yellowColor]];
[testView addSubview:self.logInView.dismissButton];
[self.logInView addSubview:testView];
}

-(void)viewDidLayoutSubviews {
[super viewDidLayoutSubviews];

[self.logInView.dismissButton setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.logInView.dismissButton.frame.size.width, self.logInView.frame.size.height)];
}
```

Comment: You definitely shouldn't be adding a new view in viewDidLayoutSubviews - this gets called _a lot_. You should add some breakpoints and see what is happening, and log the frames.

Comment: I changed the code to use viewDidLayoutSubviews property, logged the x and y positions of the frames, for both my testView and the dismissButton, and added breakpoints. The behaviour is still the same and I can't see anything wrong.